# React-select list length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-select

I am using `Select` `component` from `react-select` library. `npm i --save react-select`

https://react-select.com/home

How can I set the maximum length of list it shows? I mean, let's say I have got 20 items and when I click to `input` I only want to show 5 items and make the list scrollable where the rest of items are hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `minMenuHeight={50}` or `maxMenuHeight={100}`

```html
<Select minMenuHeight={50} maxMenuHeight={100} value={selectedValue} options={this.state.selectOptions} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-test-selected-value-jc52f experiment here.